# How to remove extra namespace like "NS1" from serialized xml in IE9?

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, internet-explorer-9

When I create a `<body>` element with attributes without colon like `ab="foo"` and serialize it using `XMLSerializer.serializeToString()`, we get:

`<body xmlns="" ab="foo" />`

which is expected. However, if I pass attributes with colon (namespaced) like `a:b="foo"`, then after serialization, IE9 makes it look like:

`<body xmlns="" xmlns:NS1="" NS1:a:b="foo" />`

which breaks our code.

I want to know why Chrome/FF/Safari/IE8 do not emit this extra NS1 stuff, while IE9 does. Any help will be great.

Comment: What is the namespace declaration for `a`? How do you "pass attributes with a colon"? Can you post more code, to help determine what the issue(s) are? `@NS1:a:b` is NOT a valid attribute. There can only be one namespace, and attribute names cannot have a ":".